# Making sure the src attribute has http:

Tags: jquery, attributes, wikipedia, src

I am using this jquery script to import parts of wikipedia articles, but I have run into an issue where when this script is putting together an image tag, it strips out "`http:`" (or rather, it was't there in the first place?) from the src attribute. How can I ensure every img tag has http: at the beginning of the src attribute without adding another one if it is already there?

Here is what I am using:

https://gist.github.com/steren/704540

Specifically this is what adds the image in (but leaves out "`http:`"):

```
//get images of right side table
var rightTableImages = content.find('table a.image img');        
//append first image to main container  
wikiContainer.append($(rightTableImages).first().removeAttr('srcset').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width').addClass("imageForArticle").wrap('<div class="wikipediaLogo"></div>').parent());
```

I have tried adding a class to the images by adding `.addClass("imageForArticle")` to the above and then tried this:

```
$('. imageForArticle').attr('src', function(index, src) {
return 'http:' + src;
});
```

But when I do that, if there are multiple articles in one page it sometimes adds an extra http: to one when I reload the page.

Comment: Why do you need that? URLs like `//example.com/` are [perfectly valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_relative_URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('. imageForArticle').attr('src', function (index, src) {
    return (src.indexOf('http') == 0) ? src : 'http:' + src;
});
```

---

if `src.indexOf('http') == 0` it starts with http than return same else add `http:`

---

Or

```
$('. imageForArticle').not('[src^="http"]').attr('src', function (index, src) {
    return 'http:' + src;
});
```

---

Exclude results with `src` strating from http `$('. imageForArticle').not('[src^="http"]')`

Comment: Does the carat `^` mean "starts with"? Thank you, that worked a treat.

Comment: @user2219915 yes Read [Attribute Starts With Selector ^](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: What about relative URLs like `../image.jpg`? Your code would change that to `http:../image.jpg`, which isn't right.

Comment: I am pulling in images from wikipedia, so none are relative urls. I'd cross that bridge if I came to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('. imageForArticle').attr('src', function (index, src) {
    return (src.indexOf('http') < 0) ? src : 'http:' + src;
});
```